# Request to show countdown to when banned account will be allowed to post a new question

Tags: feature-request, post-ban

I am requesting a feature that will display the number of days before a banned user can ask a new question on the *Question Limit Reached* page.

Something like you can ask a new question in 30 days or the specific date on when the ban will temporarily be suspended. This will enable banned users monitor the ban intervals and reduce the rate at which banned users create new accounts by encouraging patience before asking a new question.

Comment: "*reduce the rate at which banned users create new accounts by encouraging patience*" I doubt this will happen on a large enough scale to matter. Just to be clear, I still think this is a good feature to have, as it would improve the visibility. I just don't think it would have much of an impact on users creating new accounts. Seems like they would do that regardless of whether or not they know when the post ban expires.

Comment: I kind of doubt if they will wait patiently when they see "6 months" before they are able to post a new question again...

Comment: This already exists for the temporary rate limits that are imposed before a ban is imposed.

Comment: Although one might not agree with this feature request but that's not a reason to close it (That's a downvote reason). Voting to reopen since I don't see how this feature request is unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that a small sentence about date (time) of the "new attempt" to ask would benefit not only for a banned person. With appropriate wording, that sentence could give them hints for what kind of date it is and how to avoid waiting so long. It is true that all this information is already contained in the [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans). But with such addition the information will be **reinforced** to a banned person **every time** they want to refresh a date in their memory. So the community would also benefit from it.

After the last paragraph of the [current message](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans) "You can't post new questions right now":

> Please do not create a new account. Instead, work on improving your existing questions by editing them to comply with the site's guidelines and addressing any feedback you've received. You can also continue to contribute to the site in other ways, such as editing other posts to improve them.

Something like this could be added:

> If perceiving of your existing questions won't be improved, then you will have a new attempt to ask a good question after <date>.

A banned person could find in that paragraph:

1. If they don't want to wait so long, then they need to make my existing questions to be better received by the community.
2. But if their existing questions cannot be improved (this is not a rare case), then they have at least a well-defined date for when they can ask again.
3. This is not an "un-ban" date, but only is one more attempt.
4. That attempt should be a good attempt, so they need to prepare for it (not just wait).

Comment: I like this answer! I think improving the messaging is always a good thing; from what I understand about it today, the state of being question banned is kind of confusing– I don't think it's by chance that we end up with many "what does it mean to be question banned" posts every single week. Improving the wording and guidance given to these users would be a very positive change.

Comment: I'm not convinced throwing more text at humans that either missed or ignored all previous guidance is going to be helpful. On top of that: The system currently doesn't know when you will be unbanned and it is isn't a fixed date either. If any of the questions, edited or not, get an upvote they might be out of the ban. And then we get complaints the system told them the wrong date.

Comment: @rene: "If any of the questions, edited or not, get an upvote they might be out of the ban." - My original wording - "If perceiving of your existing questions won't be improved" - intentionally reflected that possibility to get out of ban even without editing the questions. (At least, I *expect* my wording to reflect that). I reverted it now.

Comment: "*If perceiving of your existing questions won't be improved,*" sounds like a *complicated* Wording and not very clear, "perceiving" cannot be improved, only Quality, maybe "better"(?) would be stg like: "Improve the quality of your existing questions to try to get them upvoted, and otherwise you will have a new attempt to ask a good question after <yyyy-mm-dd>." // And I've retracted my Upvote although I like(d) this Answer, => for using a useless Date Format in which strangely only Americans find any logic, use the International Date Format when using Dates...! :idea:

Comment: @chivracq I have changed "ymd" notation of the date to the neutral one:) As for "**perceiving**" word, it is by intention about upvotes/downvotes only: exactly those affect on the ban condition. This is somehow different from the "**improving the questions**", which is already noted in the previous paragraph. E.g. one could improve a question by fixing grammar errors. But if the question remains off-topic, such improvement is useless both for the site and for the ban evasion. If "improve" is a bad verb for the "perceiving", then what verb would be the better one? "rise"?

Comment: Hum, got your Upvote "back", ah-ah...! // "*If perceiving of your existing questions*" => "If the *score* of your existing questions" maybe...?

Answer (score 14):

That would just encourage you to focus on the wrong thing. The point is not to sit there passively counting down the days till you can ask your next question.

Fix and undelete your existing questions. If you're not sure how, look at some recent, well received questions with similar tags to yours. How are they different? Use that knowledge to improve your questions.

Answer (score 11):

> This will enable banned users monitor the ban intervals and reduce the
> rate at which banned users create new accounts by encouraging patience
> before asking a new question.

Really? Because I think it will cause exactly the opposite. We're talking about people here who are in a mode of dumping as much on Stack Overflow as possible with as little understanding of SO as possible, so if they see they can't do it for 30 days... creating a new account will sound like a really sweet deal.

No I think a certain amount of uncertainty is actually a good thing. For one it leads people to go looking for answers rather than just sitting there thinking how to stick it to the system. Whether they land on the help center or on this meta site, either is a boon.